# How to add Custom color Effect on My Custom camera in android

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I want to create my custom camera with supports different color
   effects for taking images ... I want to custom color effect on my
   camera . i put some effect that is Built_In in device but i have no
   idea that how i apply other effect like AFTER SNOW FALLING EFFECT
   from [here](http://shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/08/snow-falling-effect-on-image-in.html)
 and so many other Color Effects.

Please Give me some hints or any link that is helpful for me
My code for effect is

```
     ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.e1)).setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);

private View.OnClickListener onButtonClick = new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {   
    switch(v.getId())
          {
              case R.id.e1: MonoEffect();       
              break;} 
                 } 
                   };        

     private void MonoEffect()
        {      
       Camera.Parameters parameters =mCamera.getParameters();            
       parameters.setColorEffect(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_MONO);
       mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cameraPreviewLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    //this code is holding an realtime overlay 
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview);
    FrameLayout fr = new FrameLayout(this);
    fr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.snow);
    ImageView b1 = new ImageView(this);
    b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.snow);
    fr.addView(b1);
    layout.addView(fr);
```

/*one solution could be,you if you want a real-time effect on your camera layout,you can add an overlay on the preview as given up.snow is a png format picture with transparent background */ after that... add both the camera output and ta transparent snoweffect as..

```
Bitmap cameraBitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
Bitmap overlayBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.snow);

Bitmap cameraScaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(cameraBitmap, 1200, 1600, true);





        int wid = cameraScaledBitmap.getWidth();
        int hgt = cameraScaledBitmap.getHeight();
        Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(wid,hgt, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);



        Bitmap overlayScaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(overlayBitmap, wid, hgt, true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newImage);
        canvas.drawBitmap(cameraBitmap , 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(overlayScaledBitmap , 0, 0, null);
```

now you have got your final bitmap as named overlayScaledBitmap.now save it.dont tension about 1200,1600.i just scaled both the camera output bitmap and the snow transparent png as same size.i am currently working on the same project as you qustioned.i would like to take any suggetion from you. https://www.facebook.com/mohammad.mukul.37